# Perl Regexp::Common package not matching certain real numbers when used with word boundary

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

The following code below print "34" instead of the expected ".34"

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common;

my $regex = qr/\b($RE{num}{real})\s*/;
my $str = "This is .34 meters of cable";

if ($str =~ /$regex/) {
    print $1;
}
```

Do I need to fix my regex? (The word boundary is need as not including it will cause it match something string like `xx34` which I don't want to)

Or is it is a bug in Regexp::Common? I always thought that a longest match should win.

Comment: The current issue has nothing to do with longest or shortest match. We can speak about longest or shortest alternative in a group (then NFA, regex driven engines,like Perl or PCRE, always prefer the first, be it shortest or longest). Regex itself never matches shortest or longest string from the input, it can only be done after extracting all matches and then checking which one is shortest/longest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word boundary is a context-dependent regex construct. When it is followed with a word char (letter, digit or `_`) this location should be preceded either with the start of a string or a non-word char. In this concrete case, the word boundary is followed with a non-word char and thus requires a word char to appear right before this character.

You may use a non-ambiguous word boundary expressed with a negative lookbehind:

```
my $regex = qr/(?<!\w)($RE{num}{real})/;
               ^^^^^^^
```

The `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind always denotes one thing: fail the match if there 
 is no word character immediately to the left of the current location.

Or, use a whitespace boundary if you want your matches to only occur after whitespace or start of string:

```
my $regex = qr/(?<!\S)($RE{num}{real})/;
               ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The first regex will match `34` ( and not `.34`) in `is.34 meters`. It is possible that OP did not want to match anything in this case, as I interpret it

Comment: @Håkon Hægland I would like match `.34` (The whole "real number")

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew The regex you provided would also match the string `x.34 meters of cable`, which IHMO it shouldn't as x.34 is not a number at all.

Comment: @DemeterP.Chen Then what is the word boundary for you? A whitespace boundary? `(?<!\S)(\d*\.?\d+)`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew -  You are probably right. I would give more thought to it. `x.34` example, it is more logical to treat the . as period as opposed to a decimal point thus making 34 match the pattern. I retract the previous statement I made to you :)

Comment: @DemeterP.Chen Ok, if you ever need to precise the word boundary for your concrete case, please drop a comment,  I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this patern: `(?:^| )(\d*\.?\d+)`

Explanation:

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`^|` - match either `^` - beginning oof a string or  - space

`\d*` - match zero or more digits

`\.?` - match dot literally - zero or one

`\d+` - match one or more digits

Matched number will be stored in first capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KIIKkP/1)

Comment: The regular expression you provided doesn't match all kinds of "real number" example, negative floating point or exponential notation. They have been covered in `Regexp::Common`. Thanks for your help though. I appreciate it.